# Does Visual Studio Professional come with SQL Server Developer (not Express) edition?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005

A co-worker and I are disagreeing on this.  He thinks we have licenses for SQL Developer because we purchased VS 2005 Professional.  It's been a while since I've installed it but I don't recall that being part of the installation whatsoever.  It's always been a separate install and license.  Been to the MS VS site and can't find anything about it coming with SQL Server anywhere.  I think he is referring to the MS launch events where VS and SQL came in a pack together as part of the launch.

Anyone know for sure?  Thanks in advance.

I should add that there is a difference between sql express and sql developer.  I think express has been bundled with all kinds of things.  SQL Developer is basically Enterprise edition for developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I purchased Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition (C5E-00001).  Included in the box are 2 CDs for installing Visual Studio, 3 CDs for MSDN Library, 1 DVD for installing Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition (32bit & 64bit), a product key for Visual Studio Pro, a product key for SQL Server Developer Edition 2005, a poster pack containing some awesome posters to start fires with, and a manual.

Here's a link of Visual studio 2005 product comparison page as it looked in 2006:

http://web.archive.org/web/20060209025444/msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/products/compare/default.aspx

The short of it: You will in fact receive MS SQL 2005 Developer (32 & 64bit) DVD and Key if you purchase the Pro, or Team editions.

Best of luck, I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I bought VS2008 Pro (upgrade) recently and it came with SQL 2005 Dev edition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure VS2005 and VS2008 come with SQL Server 2005 Express Edition bundled in.

When you install VS2008 I know that machine.config gets an connection string entry for the default local SQLEXPRESS instance.

Answer (score 0):

Our company bought VS 2005 Pro a few years back, and there was definitely a copy of SQL 2005 Dev edition in the box. This is in South Africa - not sure about other countries.